# Bluetooth Low Energy IoT device compliance

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy, compliance, regulatory

I´m designing a bluetooth IoT BLE device and have heard that making use of the Bluetooth logo in the device implies an annual fee for Bluetooth SIG.
I would like to know if this only applies to the bluetooth logo and not to the technology itself.

The device will be free and inistalled by our company so it doesn´t have to have any marketing/commercial attraction for the final user.

This is, if I design a bluetooth device but don´t print the bluetooth logo in the case nor use the word bluetooth, should I have to pay for it?

Would developing an Android application making use of bluetooth require any payment or extra cost for using this technology?

Are there any additional costs on Bluetooth Low Energy qualification/certification appart from CE/FCC marking required? I´ve checked [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/145614/bluetooth-compliance) and [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/201611/bluetooth-compliance-and-qualification) questions and it isn´t clear to me yet.

As post in the first question, if we don´t need any marketing/commercial strategy, we could go ahead with the bluetooth low energy certification related to the regulatory marking laws depending on the territory, in our case CE marking, nothing else. Is this correct?

Comment: Just a suggestion: Have you considered using a BT **module** as that will make certification (and possibly marking with a logo) much easier as you would simply rely on the module's certifications and markings.

Comment: Yes, but our current situation and checking the development critical path allows us to proceed with the SoC development, about 10 months --> 6 months for HW/FW design and 4 months for certification, validation etc. (estimated time based on experience of course) We counted on CE marking but not on this Bluetooth SIG fees

Comment: If you develop your own SoC then why even **think** about the cost of BT SIG fee? I cannot imagine that that fee is as expensive as developing a SoC.

Comment: Instead of using a module we will use a SoC. We're not going to develop a SoC, we will buy it to a BLE SoC manufacturer, such as NXP, Microchip, Renesas, Cypress, Nordic ...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about EE as defined for this site.

Comment: So, EE is only related to technical questions? Wouldn't the qualification or the compliance checking of an electronic product be related to EE?

Comment: You are asking about licensing, commercial and legal responsibilities and nothing technical.

Comment: Yes, and my question is: Wouldn't the qualification or the compliance checking of an electronic product be related to EE?

Comment: I have been checking documentation and other forums and it seems that, if you use BLE stack previously qualified by Bluetooth SIG, all the testing process is accepted and you would only have to pay the fee for the listing, is this correct?